# Wrong move constructor for a struct with arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, move-semantics

Trying to debug and understand a small problem with what seems to be a move constructor, problem appears only in visual studio 2017 15.6.1, release build.

Here is the code (minimal to reproduce the problem):

---

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

const size_t kSize = 16;

class Symbol
{
  public:
    explicit Symbol(const char *const name = nullptr)
     : name_{0}
    {
      if (name)
        std::memcpy(name_, name, strlen(name));
    }

    Symbol(const Symbol& other)
    {
       std::memcpy(name_, other.name_, sizeof(name_));
    }

    Symbol& operator=(const Symbol& other)
    {
       if (this != &other)
         std::memcpy(name_, other.name_, sizeof(name_));

       return *this;
    }

    Symbol(Symbol&& other) noexcept
    {
       std::memcpy(name_, other.name_, sizeof(name_));
       std::memset(other.name_, 0, sizeof(other.name_));
    }

    const char* GetSymbolName(void) const { return name_; }

  private:
    char name_[kSize];
 };

struct MyTestMessage
{
   Symbol   symbol;
   int32_t  type;
   int32_t  other;
   int32_t  status;
   int32_t  reserved[5];

   MyTestMessage() = default;
   MyTestMessage(const MyTestMessage& msg) = default;
   MyTestMessage(MyTestMessage&& msg) = default;

   /*
   MyTestMessage(MyTestMessage&& msg) noexcept
     : symbol(std::move(msg.symbol))
  {
    status = msg.status;
    other = msg.other;
    type = msg.type;
  }*/
};

void Print(const std::vector<MyTestMessage>& data)
{
   std::cout << "------------" << std::endl;
   std::for_each(data.cbegin(), data.cend(), [](const MyTestMessage& msg)
 {
    std::cout <<msg.symbol.GetSymbolName() << " " << msg.other << " " << 
              msg.status << " " << msg.type << std::endl;
  });
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<MyTestMessage> my_test;

  MyTestMessage msg;
  msg.other = 5;
  msg.symbol = Symbol("TEST");
  msg.type = 5;
  msg.status = 5;

  my_test.push_back(msg);
  Print(my_test);
  my_test.push_back(msg);
  Print(my_test);

  return 0;
```

}

Or you can grab the code here [coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2be1191e0a8a5c6e)

Here is the output from visual studio release build:

---

TEST 5 5 5

---

TEST 5 5 0

TEST 5 5 5

---

Question is where that 0 is coming from?

Two ways to "fix it":

- add move constructor for MyTestMessage, which is commented out at the moment.
- Or comment std::memset(other.name_, 0, sizeof(other.name_)); in Symbol move constructor.

After removing any of data members (type, other, status) in MyTestMessage problem disappears.

But I do not believe either of those is correct.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**
Compiler version is visual studio 2017 15.6.1
And actually managed to find compiler setting which changes the output:
if "Enable IntrinsicFunctions" is set to: Yes (/Oi) problem is reproducible, if set to No, works as expected.

**UPDATE:**
Microsoft has responded, that it was indeed a bug and it is already fixed in VS2017 15.7 Preview 1.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/TDKH39186), for what it's worth.

Comment: Idea: Use a debugger...

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Please double check your MCVE. Perhaps you need to include some compiler settings.

Comment: Culprit seems to be "Enable Intrinsic Functions" on visual studio 2017 15.6.1

Comment: You should self-answer this question to make it clear that this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

So nothing wrong with the code.

It appears to be a bug in VS. Supposedly fixed in VS2017 15.7 Preview 1.

Answer (score -3):

> Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

You're using pointers when you just don't need to. Just use:

```
 struct Symbol { char name[kSize]; };
```

For what you have in your example. ... although, frankly, unless there's a good reason not to, stick to `std::string`.

Comment: `Symbol("TEST")` won't compile with just that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Yes, it will - if you use curly brackets; see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbd81361ac5b6693)

Comment: In any case, this doesn't really answer the question. The original code looks correct to me, with well-defined behavior that should produce expected output. An argument over stylistic points doesn't address why this code (allegedly) doesn't work as written.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: OP didn't ask why the code does not work as written (which actually it might just...), he asked what he was doing wrong. I've answered that.

Comment: @einpoklum actual code is more complicated, this is minimal amount of code to reproduce the problem. For one, strings might use dynamic memory, which will degrade performance.

Comment: @Tadzys: That's why I didn't suggest strings to begin with. This struct should serve you well - likely better than your own code, since you're giving the compiler more leeway to optimize things by not implementing your own methods. Also - remember you're not the only reader of this question and answer; other users only see what you've provided as an example, so my advice about `std::string` stands.