# Could a char[] be moved into a rvalue?

Tags: c++, overloading

If I have two overload function like

```
void f1(const char(&)[4]) {
    std::cout << "f1 lvalue" << std::endl;
}

void f1(char(&&)[4]) {
    std::cout << "f1 rvalue" << std::endl;
}
```

And when I call

```
    char s[] = "asd";

    f1(move(s));
    f1(s);
```

They both call `f1` with the lvalue version.
So how could I pass varable to call `f1` with the rvalue version，or is it feasible. Or otherwise, is there any mistake in my overload versions of `f1`?

**ADDED**
Under msvc x64 with -std=c++17

Comment: Cannot reproduce: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dxE18sea1). Which compiler are you using ?

Comment: @wohlstad Under msvc x64 with -std=c++17

Comment: Couldn't reproduce on MSVC as well. I am using VS2022 (17.2.5), with x64, /std:c++17.

Comment: @wohlstad hmmm... I'm using VS2017, does it matter?

Comment: Did you try the exact code posted in the first comment, or something else? What is your compiler version?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat On 14.16, with `/std::c++latest` it IS  reproduceable, at least. Are we punching a known bug spot?

Comment: Hmm, disabling lvalue reference function works for the first call correctly... apparently naive implementation casts `char(&&)[4]` to `char[4]` contextually

Comment: seems to be msvc v.14 bug.  v.15 also shows similar behaviour if intrinstic functions are enabled... a takeout: do not use move semantic with C-strings and other raw arrays

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug with v.14 and v.15 Microsoft compilers. Use newer compiler or avoid raw-array move.

There are other issues: [Wrong move constructor for a struct with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258095/wrong-move-constructor-for-a-struct-with-arrays)

Inherently it's not a problem with `std::move` but with how compiler treats `T(&&)[]` family of types as `const T(&)[]`. Which may cause huge issues with some super-optimized containers, e.g. while writing ECS. I'm currenly looking at list of bugs in BGS game "Starfield" and many of these can be explained by this bug..